# Top Down View Shooter, issues with mouse rotation

Tags: c++, sfml

Im following along to the book 'Beginning C++ Game Programming' I tried manipulating some of the code to a structure which best fits me and looks neater but unfortunately in doing so I have come across an issue, which I believe I know where the problem is but i'm struggling to fix it.

The player looks around dependent on the mouse position, but when actually playing it seems to not able to look around 360 degrees. My first initial guess is this is because when I convert mouse position to world coordinates of my mainView, it doesn't convert to the mainView properly and thus it's using numbers way beyond my screen resolution. This guess may be wrong, I am completely new with Views, here is some of the code in which I believe the issue is at, does it look right?

---

main.cpp

```
void Game::initWindow()
{
    // Start with the GAME_OVER state
    state = State::GAME_OVER;
    
    // Get the screen resolution and create an SFML window
    resolution.x = VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width;
    resolution.y = VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height;
    
    this->window = new RenderWindow(VideoMode(resolution.x, resolution.y), "Zombie Arena", Style::Fullscreen);

    mainView.reset(sf::FloatRect(0, 0, resolution.x, resolution.y)); // setting the mainView
}

//Frame Update
void Game::updateFrame()
{
    if (state == State::PLAYING)
    {
        //Time Update
        Time dt = clock.restart();
        gameTimeTotal += dt;
        float dtAsSeconds = dt.asSeconds(); // Make a decimal fraction of 1 from the delta time
        
        //Mouse Update
        mouseScreenPosition = Mouse::getPosition(); // Where is the mouse pointer
        
        // Convert mouse position to world coordinates of mainView
        mouseWorldPosition = window->mapPixelToCoords(Mouse::getPosition(), mainView);
        
        // Update the player
        player->update(dtAsSeconds, Mouse::getPosition());
        
        // Make a note of the players new position
        Vector2f playerPosition(player->getCenter());
        
        // Make the view centre around the player
        mainView.setCenter(player->getCenter());
    }
}

//Render stuff//
void Game::render()
{
    if (state == State::PLAYING)
    {
        //clear window
        window->clear();
        
        // set the mainView to be displayed in the window and draw everything related to it
        window->setView(mainView);
        
        // Draw the player
        player->renderTo(window);
    }
    
    //Display Window
    window->display();
}
```

Player.cpp

```
void Player::update(float elapsedTime, Vector2i mousePosition)
{
    // Calculate the angle the player is facing
    float angle = (atan2(mousePosition.y - windowRes.y / 2,
    mousePosition.x - windowRes.x / 2) * 180) / 3.141;
    
    playerSprite.setRotation(angle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you dividing collinears vectors by two? If I was you, I should write like that:

```
    float dX = mousePosition.x - sprite.x;//vector, collinear straight line whicn crosses sprite an cursor on X axis;
    float dY = mousePosition.y - sprite.y;//same, but to Y axis;
    
    float angle = (atan2(dY, dX)*180)/3.14159;//CALCULATING ANGLE
    sprite.setRotation(angle + 90);
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to set the rotation angle is :

```
    float rotationAngle = atan2f(this->mousePos.y - player.getPosition().y, this- 
    >mousePos.x - player.getPosition().x) * 180 / PI;
```

Answer (score 0):

When sending the position of your mouse to the player, you are doing it by sending the mouse position in your SCREEN, not in your GAME VIEW. You could do that easily by using the variable you declared above:

```
mouseWorldPosition = window->mapPixelToCoords(Mouse::getPosition(), mainView);
player->update(dtAsSeconds, mouseWorldPosition);
```

Doing this will prevent mouse placement mistakes that could occur using the mouse placement on screen.

You should change that, as well as the angle code provided by earlier answers.